# USB only detected when connected to internet

Tags: ubuntu, usb, usb-drive

For some reason, my laptop does not detect USBs at all unless I am connected to the internet. (I also am not very good at using Ubuntu, so I have no idea what could cause the problem.)

Note: I have tried searching, but I am not sure how to get relevant results.

Comment: Define "detect". Turn off the internet, then run `lsusb`. And how are you connecting to the net?

Comment: Connecting via wireless. lsusb shows linux root hub, teminus hub, chicony, another linux root hub with usb and no internet

Comment: Can you run `lsusb` with and without the wireless, and post the output in your question, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you relying completely on a popup, in order to open the USB storage?

Popups are great but they are a bit ephemeral.  I.e. have you tried looking in the file manager for the USB?  The file manager should have a panel on the left hand side, which includes USB storage devices (as well as e.g. Documents).  I've had people struggle to find them in the list - you can always plug / unplug the USB device and look for an entry that appears / disappears.

(File manager will be one of the icons in the app launcher by default.  Sit the cursor over an icon and leave it, to get a tooltip showing the name of the app.  Or use search - open the app launcher (e.g. press the "Windows" key on your keyboard), and just start typing "File", it should show names underneath the search results).

If the failure case also stops the USB device from showing up in the file manager (i.e. you can get it to work when connected to the internet)?  I think that's a pretty solid result.

I don't use Ubuntu personally, but it's so weird it's probably going to require a lot of investigation to fix.  Not just a simple support case.  You could try reporting it as a bug in Ubuntu.  That doesn't guarantee anything, it just gives Ubuntu an opportunity to process it.  If they determine it's important, you could get some investigation support from a developer, or information that they already have about the problem.

---

I don't really have any ideas.  But if you want to you could play around with typing a few commands in the Terminal.  (Hit windows key to bring up the app launcher, type "term", click on the Terminal result).

```
udevadm monitor --kernel
```

You want to see a load of "add" events when you plug the USB in, including for a name ending in `block/sdb` or `block/sdc` etc.

(Then close Terminal, which will cancel the command, or press Ctrl+C to get back to the command prompt).

```
udisksctl monitor
```

This command should show three detailed events that we're interested in, when you plug in the USB.

1. `Added ... block_devices/sdb`
2. a `job` with the detail `Operation: filesystem-mount`
3. a `Properties Changed` event for `sdb`, which shows the `MountPoints`.  This indicates success.

E.g. maybe you're seeing the MountPoint success, but there's some problem with the file manager that stops the USB being displayed.  I believe the package name of the file manager is `nautilus`; you will need to know that in order to follow the bug reporting procedure.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/FindRightPackage

But my best guess would be a nasty hardware/driver interaction.  You could look at

```
journalctl -f
```

(not sure if that will work on your version of ubuntu) or maybe

```
dmesg --follow
```

and look for exciting error messages when you plug in.  It's hard to characterise what you would be looking for any more specifically.  But you can just look for differences between the success and failure cases :).

If you can see error messages in `dmesg` specifically, [then any bug report should probably be made against the kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/FindRightPackage#Kernel) package, which is called `linux`.

They're horribly strict about hardware reports because of the volume of reports they accept.  That is, they'll probably require you to upgrade your BIOS to the latest version, before doing any investigation.

Comment: it does not show as a drive at all (i.e. no `sdb`/`sdc` etc.) when I have no internet, but it works perfectly fine when I am connected. When I am not connected to the internet, `dmesg` shows nothing about the USB being plugged in (I checked by running it before and after I put the USB in.)

Comment: Haven't checked anything else though, gonna check tomorrow.

Comment: That probably exhausts my ideas, I'm afraid.  (If dmesg doesn't show anything for a usb device, then I assume there's nothing in  `udevadm monitor`.  And definitely not in `udisksctl monitor`).